# Sidr plugin- how does $.sidr work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the Sidr plugin from http://www.berriart.com/sidr/# for my website

From the source code there is this block of code that I don't understand how it's supposed to work. I tried commenting it out but it didn't do anything.

```
$.sidr = function( method ) {

if ( methods[method] ) {
  return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
}
else if ( typeof method === 'function' || typeof method === 'string' || ! method ) {
  return methods.toggle.apply( this, arguments );
}
else {
  $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.sidr' );
}
```

Here is the link to the source code [the source code of the Sidr plugin](https://github.com/artberri/sidr/blob/master/src/jquery.sidr.js)

Can anyone elaborate on this a bit ? I am still quite new to jQuery

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify the source code for the plugin itself; you can just include it in your page and never look at the code. If you want to understand how it works internally, that's fine, but you should start by understanding how jQuery's plugin system works in general before trying to understand the code of individual plugins. If you understand how jQuery plugins work, then you'll find the above code makes sense.

Comment: @Simba I have read the tutorial from jQuery website but it doesn't have similar format. Can you give some resources that I can read about how plugins in jquery work?

Comment: @Simba also in the code later on there is `$.fn.sidr` already, so I don't quite get why there is another `$.sidr`before it